# Is there a way to group certain rows together in an Excel table, and then sort those groups into date order?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula

I have a large Excel table full of customer orders for certain products;
this table is sorted and manipulated by a VBA macro.

*The table headers are as follows:*
`Order Date   |   Name   |   Product   |   Order Quantity   |   Stock Quantity   |   In stock`

If I have enough of the product in stock to cover the customers order, the row will be highlighted, and set to *'In stock'* in the last column.
Orders can ONLY be sent when every single order that the customer has placed is in stock.
So, my table filters all fully complete orders to the top of the table, where they are sorted alphabetically to keep each customers orders together.

What I want is for these fully complete customer orders at the top of the list to be displayed in order of who has the oldest dated order first, but also keep the orders grouped by customer name.

So for example:

- ***David** has an order due **24/08***
- ***John** has an order due **17/08**, and another due **30/08***

Alphabetically, David's order would show first, because my list is primarily sorted by *Name* to keep the customer orders together.
But because John has an order with the oldest due date, I want both of **John's** orders to be **displayed at the top** in date order, and then **David's** order **below**.

---

Here is an example of what I currently have:

```
Order Date  Name    Product     In stock?

07/09/2023  Angela  Example     In stock
24/08/2023  David   Example     In stock
17/08/2023  John    Example     In stock
30/08/2023  John    Example     In stock

25/08/2023  Andy    Example     .
01/09/2023  Andy    Example     In stock
24/08/2023  Holly   Example     .
17/08/2023  Holly   Example     In stock
```

---

And what I want it to look like:

```
Order Date  Name    Product     In stock?

17/08/2023  John    Example     In stock
30/08/2023  John    Example     In stock
24/08/2023  David   Example     In stock
07/09/2023  Angela  Example     In stock

25/08/2023  Andy    Example     .
01/09/2023  Andy    Example     In stock
24/08/2023  Holly   Example     .
17/08/2023  Holly   Example     In stock
```

*(Andy and Holly still have orders that are not in stock, so they are below)*

Comment: The short answer for your question is `Yes` Excel can does it. But this site is for improving editing debugging and a lot more but not for complete program generating. So pls. describe what you tried to achieve and include the relevant part of code what you have.

Comment: The problem I am having is that I have no idea where to even start to solve this sorting problem using VBA code, I don't know how I can keep the customers grouped together while still ordering them by date.
I was hoping that someone many know if this is at all possible to solve using a more rudimentary Excel function first, if not then it needs to be done using code.

Comment: How abut proofreading and correcting your question. In your posted data, there is no `Adam` in your data. There is no `Order Due` column. There are no dates of `23/08` or `16/08`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the two examples I posted are unrelated. The first example was just a visual example to show the logic behind what I am trying to achieve. The second example is actual example data. The 'Order Date' column IS the 'Order Due' column.

Comment: I believe your question would be more clear if your description matched your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual table name and column headers
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Order Date", type date}, {"Name", type text}, {"Product", type text}, {"In stock?", type text}}),

//Group by "Name"
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {

    //Aggregate by "All" rows
        {"All", each _, 
            type table [Order Date=nullable date, Name=nullable text, Product=nullable text, #"In stock?"=nullable text]}, 

    //Aggregate by Minimum date UNLESS not all entries are "in stock"
    //   in which case return "false" so it will sort to bottom   
        {"MinDate", each if List.ContainsAll({"In Stock"},[#"In stock?"],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                        then   List.Min([Order Date])
                        else false , type nullable date}}),

//Sort by the MinDate column and Name columns
//  then remove the MinDate column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"MinDate", Order.Ascending}, {"Name", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"MinDate"}),

//Re-Expand the grouped table
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "All", {"Order Date", "Product", "In stock?"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```vb
= LET(n,data[Name],
dMin,BYROW(n,LAMBDA(nn,MIN(FILTER(data[Order Date],n=nn)))),
dComplete,BYROW(n,LAMBDA(nn,COUNTIFS(n,nn,data[in Stock?],"."))),
SORTBY(data,IF(dComplete=0,dComplete,n),1,dMin,1))
```

[image]

The basic idea is to use `SORTBY`.
As input for `SORTBY` `dMin` and `dComplete` are calculated.

`dMin` calculates per name the min-date.

`dComplete` calculates per name wether all products are in stock. If yes, it returns 0. This is then used by the Sortby: if 0 use 0 as sort criteria, if <> then use name.

You will have to format the date-column as date - otherwise you see only the numerical values of each date